# SQL: windowed aggregate functions for DB2 iSeries

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

Is `count` not a valid aggregation function for row partitions for SQL DB2 on the iSeries?

This query works:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by COL1, COL2 order by COL3 asc)
from MyTable
```

And this query gives a syntax error:

```
select COUNT(1) over (partition by COL1, COL2)
from MyTable
```

The error message is pointing at the parenthesis before the word `partition`:

> [Message SQL0401] Token ( is not a valid token. A partial list of valid tokens is , FROM INTO.

I'm aware I can rewrite the query to avoid the row partition, but I'd like to know why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [COUNT()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzcolfunc.htm) is not the same [type of function as ROW_NUMBER()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzolapexp.htm).

If you want the number of rows per (col1,col2) then you could simply use

```
select COL1, COL2, count(*)
  from MyTable
  group by col1, col2
```

Comment: Am I reading that correctly: the only functions that are allowed are `RANK`, `DENSE_RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER`? None of the aggregation functions work?

Comment: Those are the only functions that use "OLAP" (partition over) syntax.  Aggregate functions work fine.  (see the first link)