# Making TWO row values into one column, and another row value another column, with the possibility of adding more row values into columns

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I know just the basics of SQL, and recently at work I stumbled across this situation. It is kinda difficult for me to visualize the problem but I will try my best to explain it.
I have two tables:

Table A:

```
IDA       SomeInfo 
-------  ----------
1        info1
2        info2
3        info3
4        info4
```

Table B:

```
IDB      IDA      VarName  VarValue
-------  -------  -------  ---------
1        1        Depth    2
2        1        Length   10
3        2        Depth2   3
4        2        Length   12
5        2        Height   35
6        3        Depth2   2
7        3        Length   11
8        3        Height   38
9        4        Depth    4
10       4        Length   16
```

And I need to join them in order to get the following result:

```
                   Depth
IDA      SomeInfo  Depth2   Length   Height
-------  --------  -------  -------  ---------
1        info1     2        10       0
2        info2     3        12       35
3        info3     2        11       38
4        info4     4        16       0
```

As you can see, I need to put two different VarNames from B's rows into one column, and the other VarNames as different columns. Each with their respective VarValue and IDA, and then when an IDA does not have some VarVal, it need to be 0. I had the following code in my c# string query and worked just fine when I only had to deal with "Depth" and "Depth2":

```
SELECT 
A.IDA, A.SomeInfo,
CASE 
    WHEN (B.VarValue IS NULL) THEN 0
    WHEN B.VarName = 'Depth' OR B.VarName = 'Depth2' THEN B.VarValue
END AS Depth
FROM A LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT B.IDA, B.VarName, B.VarValue FROM B 
    WHERE (B.VarName = 'Depth' OR B.VarName = 'Depth2')
) B ON (A.IDA = B.IDA)
```

Then I needed to add more VarNames, so I changed the code as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.IDA, A.SomeInfo,
    CASE 
        WHEN (B.VarName = 'Depth' OR B.VarName = 'Depth2') AND B.VarValue IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN B.VarName = 'Depth' OR B.VarName = 'Depth2' THEN B.VarValue
    END AS Depth,
    CASE
        WHEN B.VarName = 'Length' AND B.VarValue IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN B.VarName = 'Length' THEN B.VarValue
    END AS Length
    CASE
        WHEN B.VarName = 'Height' AND B.VarValue IS NULL THEN 0
        WHEN B.VarName = 'Height' THEN B.VarValue
    END AS Height
FROM A LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT B.IDA, B.VarName, B.VarValue FROM B 
        WHERE (B.VarName = 'Depth' OR B.VarName = 'Depth2' OR B.VarName = 'Length' OR 
        B.VarName = 'Height')
    ) B ON (A.IDA = B.IDA)
```

But now I get one row for each VarName. What should I do to get this done?

EDIT: Both answers in this question work for the example I gave, but the one marked is the one that worked the best for me. I had an issue related to DB2 and how the data is structured in an as400 but I figured it out and now everything works. Thanks to T.S. and Gordon Linoff for their answers. They helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select a.ida, a.someinfo,
       sum(case when varname in ('Depth', 'Depth2') then varvalue end) as depth,
       sum(case when varname in ('Length') then varvalue end) as length,
       sum(case when varname in ('Height') then varvalue end) as depth
from tablea a left join
     tableb b
     on a.ida = b.ida
group by a.ida, a.someinfo;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=04b7cd330530dd12f3d634af442549ac) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This works for the example I wrote, but for some reason when I try to use it on the app I'm working on I get some weird exception... (The tables where I get the data from are from an AS400, it is a bit of a mess) 
Could you elaborate a little bit on how this works? Specifically, the sum(case when). Maybe if I fully understand how this works I could solve my issue.

Comment: @ArminAH . . . What part of this do you not understand?  You might want to use `max()` instead of `sum()` if `varvalue` is not a number.

Comment: Why are we using SUM or MAX to encapsulate the CASE WHEN? I know SUM just sums the values in an expression, and MAX returns the highest value in an expression. But I don't see the point of doing that.

Comment: @ArminAH . . . An aggregation query won't work without aggregation functions.

Comment: I see. Thank you. This might be too much to ask but, do you happen to know an alternative way of making this aggregation query? Someone else had a problem using an aggregation query for the DB2 iSeries, just like me. (specifically, the OP from this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942415/sql-windowed-aggregate-functions-for-db2-iseries)) And it looks like I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: This query should work fine in DB2.  There was a dangling comma that I just removed.

Comment: It did not :( I even made another question some hours ago because I'm getting a weird exception. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: @ArminAH . . . I added a db<>fiddle (and fixed the capitalization of the strings).  The code is Standard SQL and works in DB2.

Comment: Yes, I used your code yesterday on SQL and worked flawlessly. The problem is when I try to retrieve data from the as400 using that query. For some strange reason it does not work there. This might be something to do with the way data is structured in said as400, but your code works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code - use inline view

```sql
select a.IDA, a.SomeInfo, dep.depth, hei.Height, le.Length
from 
   TableA a left join  
   (select IDA, VarValue as depth from tableB where varName = 'depth' ) dep
       on a.ida = dep.ida letf join
   (select IDA, VarValue as height from tableB where varName = 'height' ) hei
       on a.ida = hei.ida letf join 
   (select IDA, VarValue as Length from tableB where varName = 'Length' ) le
       on a.ida = le.ida
```

No doubt, there are other ways. I am old-style

I am not sure what is the DB-structural setup. For example, I don't know id the same `IDA` can have both, `depth` and `depth2`. If only one of those values is possible then you can change filter like

```
select IDA, VarValue as depth from tableB where varName in ('depth', 'depth2')
```

But if both is possible, we need another join, and `COALESCE` in select.

```sql
Select ...., COALESCE(dep.depth, dep2.depth2) as depth
....
   (select IDA, VarValue as depth from tableB where varName = 'depth' ) dep
       on a.ida = dep.ida letf join 
   (select IDA, VarValue as depth2 from tableB where varName = 'depth2' ) dep2
       on a.ida = dep2.ida letf join ...
```

Comment: After making some adjustments to your code (grammar and table names) I could make it run, but didn't completely work. I get NULL in the depth column from IDAs 2 and 3. Here it should have "depth2" values.

Comment: @ArminAH I added explanation in the answer on additional work